# LINQ query for Select top visited category

Tags: c#, linq

I write the query in SQL to select top 12 visited categories by clickCount column

```
SELECT top(12) c.Name
FROM Category c
GROUP BY c.Name
ORDER BY SUM(ClickCount) DESC
```

I need to implement in linq. so far I write this but result is not as expected

```
var query = _categoryRepository.Queryable()
                .GroupBy(r => r.Name)
                .SelectMany(g => g.OrderBy(r => r.ClickCount))
                .Take(12).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var query = (from item in _categoryRepository.Queryable()
            group item by item.Name into sub
            orderby sub.Sum(x => x.ClickCount) descending
            select sub).Take(12).ToList();
```

Comment: it return list of strings

Comment: i need to return category entity

Comment: Yes, your query also returns list of strings: SELECT top(12) **c.Name**